# Python - extracting data and splitting while removing \n

Tags: python, string, file, split

Total beginner with Python.

I have a file that I have opened and read using:

```
with open("filename.csv", 'r') as infile:
    file_data = infile.readlines()
```

Results in:

```
file_data = ['Portland, 14/02/2020, 240\n', 'Eugene, 03/01/2020, 134\n', 'Cordiva, 19/03/2020, 102\n']
```

I am trying to break it up further and remove the \n at the end.

I have tried:

```
for line in file_data: 
   new_data = line.split.rstrip('\n)
   new_data = line.split(',')
```

I know that I need to loop through the lists but I am missing something important.

ETA:

What I am looking for is:

```
file_data = [['Portland', '14/02/2020', '240'], ['Eugene', '03/01/2020', '134'], ['Cordiva', '19/03/2020', '102']]
```

ETA2:

If I use

```
 for line in file_data: 
       new_data = line.rstrip('\n')
       new_data = line.split(',')
   print(new_data)
```

I get this result:

```
['Cordiva', ' 19/03/2020', ' 102\n']
```

Comment: What isn't working as expected? Is there an error message?

Comment: `line.rstrip()` will work.

Comment: I fixed the missing ' . Then it says "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'rstrip'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
with open("filename.csv", 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
    city, date, number = line.split(", ")
    print("City:", city)
    print("Date:", date)
    print("Number:", number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_data = [[line.strip('\n')] for line in file_data]
```